# What is the exact connection between linux version / kernel and later on to install flash player and other programs?

Tags: kernel, flash, fan

What is the exact connection between linux version / kernel and later on to install flash player and other programs?
I heared a lot that later on to install the latest version of flash player for browsers or internet depends or connects to linux version and / or kernel version and sometimes it is unpossible at all later to install the latest version of flash player or some other newest program when linux or kernel version don't fits the latest one? Is it so? And up to which versions of linux / kernel and flash player / programs it stay in connection in the meaning of installation possibility? What is the exact connection between the above written. How exact linux and software developers handle these things in meaning of installation possibility? Where it is more to read about this stuff in the manner 
on Linux / kernel ver. _____ it is possible to install program_____ only_______ up to ver. ______

Answer (score 0):

**Adobe flashplayer for linux** is no longer supported, so for most versions of Ubuntu the version of flash is stuck at `11.2.202.554` in the multiverse.

There is **pepperflash** though which is still updated. In general though the version that is available depends more on which version of Ubuntu you are running, than on the particular kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

The exact kernel version is pretty irrelevant for most software you install!

What is important is the distribution (Ubuntu) and its release version (e.g. 15.10 = "Wily Werewolf"). I haven't seen any application yet which would directly depend on a specific kernel version. All programs depend on other packages, some of them must meet a specific version number, for others it's irrelevant. But e.g. Flash Player does not require specific kernel versions.

---

To get a more up-to-date version of Flash Player...

- ... for Chromium or other PPAPI-browsers:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
  ```

  It will download Google Chrome, which contains a new Flash version (19.?) for the PPAPI plug-in interface, extract it, and make it accessible to other browsers.
- ... for Firefox or other NPAPI-browsers:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash
  ```

  It will install `pepperflash-plugin-nonfree` above and add a PPAPI-to-NPAPI wrapper to the extracted Flash plugin, so that NPAPI browsers like Firefox can use it.